# Google Sheets API with NodeJS, Json error

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I've been playing with the google sheets API in NodeJS for the past couple of days and I'm having some trouble. I took one of the examples from their docs and edited it to suit my needs, however at one point it started returning an error. The console logs:

> The API returned an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ﻿ in JSON at position 0

Here's my code:

```
function getApplies(auth) {


  const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: '1g5kYIIQy5f-UTSmOatTBPOto13ccfPvsJKQpxT6lhjE',
      range: 'A2:I',
  }, (err2, res) => {
    if (err2) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err2);
    const rows = res.data.values;

    if (rows.length) {
      //saving data here...
    }
  });
}
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried inspecting `res`? It might give more details on which API call is failing. It looks like some parameter that should be JSON isnt quite parsing correctly.

Comment: I did, It looks like a regular response. Console.log(res); Shows the res object, with data, in which 130 arrays are stored. However, `const rows = res.data.values;` gives the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`
@James

Comment: NathanReul if `res` is successful (so has data and has a status code of 2xx) then the issue will be the format of the data coming back. Can you should a sample of the response data?

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/google-spreadsheets-and-javascriptnode-js.html):

1. Go to Google Console
2. Create a new Credential of type service account key
3. Download your json file
4. npm install google-spreadsheet@2.0.3

   ```
   var GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');

   var creds = require('./client_secret.json');

   var doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('*spreadsheet ID*');

   doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds, function (err) {
       doc.getRows(1, function (err, rows) {
               if (err) {
                   console.log(err);
               } else {
                   console.log(rows.length);
                   console.log(rows);
                   for (var i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                       console.log(rows[i].TITLE-NAME-OF-YOUR-FIRST-COLUMN, rows[i].TITLE-NAME-OF-YOUR-SECOND-COLUMN);
                   }
               }
       });
   });
   ```
5. Replace the spreadsheet ID with the ID found in the spreadsheet URL.
6. Share the sheet with the service account email. It is in your json file.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

For v4 of googleapi use:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const key = require("service_account_credentials.json");

const client = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key, [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
]);

client.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
  const gsapi = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: client });
  const opt = {
    spreadsheetId: "spreadsheetId",
    range: "Sheet1!A:T",
  };
  gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(opt).then(res => console.log(res));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to parse your json file like this, first:

```
const rows = JSON.parse(res.data.values);
```

Comment: But the API returns the error, look at the line above that.

Comment: Oh yeah...it is before that! Let me take a look again!

Comment: Can i take a look at your spreadsheet? I can try reading it with another nodejs module to debug.

Comment: I wish! I'm not the owner of this spreadsheet, building this for someone else

Comment: Ok. From the google-spreadsheet npm module you are missing your json credentials. That a look at this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet

Comment: You need to go to your google console and create a credential with the type Service account so you can create and download a json for authorization.

Comment: I did that, credentials.json is in there. For some reason, it works when i use their complete example with my credentials and token, but as soon as i change it to what i need it gives errors :x

Comment: I think you need to authorize your email in the share button of the sheet and also place your email in the credentials file. I post another answer for you. One suggestion: Create one sheet so that you can get access to it and test if the code is working, this way we eliminate those permissions issues.